# What kind of org environment should I use for developing integration app purpose

Tags: isv, developer-edition, org

My company has a PHP website app. And we are now thinking about building the integration with Salesforce. So based on my understanding, we would build an app in app exchange to integrate with the PHP app, which consists of several triggers, custom objects and a few VF pages and tabs. And the package will probably expand in the future.

My question is in this case, which kind of org should we be using? Traditional Production/Sandbox structure doesn't seem to suit in this case because we are just developing an app for our customers. Developer edition seems to be very attractive to me since it is free. But I am not sure whether there will be issues with it. Another option is using TSO/ISVforce orgs. It seems to be the default option for a company to develop apps on App Exchange. And becoming an ISV partner can raise cases for Salesforce support which will probably be needed in the future. But I can't think of other benefits aside from it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The developer orgs created from Environment Hub have larger limits then the normal dev orgs. So probably that would be more feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For package development one should always try to use Partner Developer orgs because they are super sized orgs.

[image]

See this for more information:[Partner Development, Test, and Demo Environments‌ (Editions Comparison)](https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerNews?id=a033000000FnswAAAR)

There are several other benefits also of **Environment hub**:

1.You can spin as many orgs as you want.That would be helpful for testing purpose.

2.**Single sign on** feature enables you to login in all of them once.

3.You can **raise cases** to get support.

There are many more...

Comment: how to become ISV Partner?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy It's pretty simple actually see this: [Sign Up for the Partner Program](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv1_1_quickstart.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Developer Editions are considered best for such cases as they are free and don't have some trial period associated with them. Here is some supportive documentation from Salesforce:
[App Distribution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_intro.htm).

The only problem that we came across with developer editions is number of licences. Dev editions has limited number of licenses and if app has multi user/profile/license requirements, it becomes little tough to go with developer editions. For such cases Partner Developer editions can be considered as better option. Also there is option to start with development edition and then to add some more licenses by contacting Salesforce support.